# How to resolve '.class' expected error?

Tags: java

Currently I have an error - '.class' expected -  on line 40. Any help is hugely appreciated.

```
    import java.io.*; // For File class and FileNotFoundException
import java.util.Scanner; //For the Scanner class
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // For the JOptionPane class
/**
 * Write a description of class PartB here.
 * 
 * @Hubble, Kieran 
 * @Version 0.1
 */
public class PartB
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file; //for file input
        Scanner inputFile; //for file input
        String fileName; //to hold a file name
        String paragraph; //to extract the letter frequencies

        //get a file name from the user.
        fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter " + " the name of the file");

        //attempt to open the file.
        try
        {
            file = new File(fileName);
            inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the file was found.");

            // read the input file, processing data one line at a time
            while(inputFile.hasNext())
            { 
                String str = inputFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }

            //create an Output file
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("crackedcode.txt");

            while(paragraph.length() > 0)
            // error is occurring on the next line (line 40)
            int[]; letterCount = new int[26];
            for (int count = 0; count < paragraph.length; count++) {
                String current = paragraph[count];
                char[] letters = current.toCharArray();
            }  

            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < letters.length; count2++) { char lett = letters[count2]; if ( (lett >= 'A') & (lett <= 'Z') ) {
                        letterCount[lett - 'A']++;
                    }
                }


            for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
                System.out.print(count + ": " +
                    letterCount[count - 'A'] +
                    " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            // close the input file
            inputFile.close();
        }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file not found.");
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done.");
    System.exit(0); //terminate program
}

}
```

Comment: JavaScript and Java are absolutely different things. Please retag your question.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the semicolon

```
int[]; letterCount = new int[26];
```

should be

```
int[] letterCount = new int[26];
```

Also, You need to wrap the block of the while (from the line above it) with `{}`